# "MapboxGeocoder is not a constructor" when trying to initialize a MapboxGeocoder inside the ts of my component

Tags: angular, typescript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to add the mapbox geocoding feature to my web app but when I try to initialize it the error comes in.

I've tried searching almost on every library inside the node_modules/mapbox-gl-geocoder for some constructor or something to see if I'm importing the wrong library but no success, If tried reading in the documentation but nothing either.

```
import  { MapboxGeocoder } from "mapbox-gl-geocoder";
.    
.
.
this.map.addControl(new MapboxGeocoder({
      accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken
}));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import * as MapboxGeocoder from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder';
```

Solved the problem by replacing the current import with the one above.